# Unsigned char is printing -ve answer when printed in binary

Tags: c

Objective is to print binary output of -ve or +ve integers and output is correct when we declare variable with signed, but not able to understand the behaviour when variable is declared as unsigned.

```
  int main() {
      unsigned char num = -1; /* unsigned int */
      int i = 0;
      /* Loop to print binary values */
      for (i = 0 ; i < 8; i++) {
        if(num & 128u)
        {
         printf("1 ");
        }
        else 
        {
         printf("0 ");
        }
        num= num<<1;
      }
      printf("\n");
      return 0;
    }
```

> output is printed as "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"

which is equal to -1; But i have given `unsigned int` as input. How this works?

Comment: Can you explain in your question what would you expect the output to be, and why?

Comment: You do not have an `unsigned int`, you have an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you doing

```
unsigned char num = -1; /* unsigned int */
```

It storing in `num`  is 255 (Max Number) in decimal. So in every loop `if(num & 128u)` is satisfying so the o/p is ....

> /* output is printed as "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" */

There are some more mistakes in question you are saying abot `int` but in program you have taken `char` variable and storing `signed` number in `unsigned` variable so , you will not get o/p what you expect.

Comment: Thanks , this give some idea.. but given a binary representation of numbers can we know it is signed or unsigned int.  I want to convert binary to decimal ..

Comment: signed binary representation may help you .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952123/representation-of-negative-numbers-in-c

Comment: how to know if a binary number represents a negative number? ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794653/how-to-know-if-a-binary-number-represents-a-negative-number